# Logging mod_rewrite on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to troubleshoot mod_rewrite on Apache2.2.15 operating on Centos 6.5.  My `httpd.conf` file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite/html
    <Directory "/var/www/somesite/html">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
            RewriteLogLevel 3
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I keep on getting the following error where line 1044 corresponds to `RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log`.

```
[root@devserver httpd]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 1044 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
RewriteLog not allowed here
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@devserver httpd]#
```

I can add `RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log` to the main section (not virtual host) of httpd.conf, but nothing gets logged from the virtual host.

How do I log mod_rewrite transactions?

Comment: [Per the docs,](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) the valid contexts for `RewriteLog` are only server-level and VirtualHost. It's an error to put it in `<Directory>` context. Are you sure it doesn't work correctly at the VirtualHost level?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  All I know for sure is it doesn't work given how I set up my virtual host as described above.  Please elaborate.  Thank you

Comment: What I mean is, place `RewriteEngine On RewriteLog` etc. up above the `<Directory>` block but still inside the `<VirtualHost>` block.If you aren't getting logging when it is placed in there, 1) check your error log 2) Manually create the `rewrite.log` file and give the Apache user ownership of it or make it writable by apache.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Thanks Michael, I think that was the problem.  Note that I only moved `RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 3`, but left `RewriteEngine On` in the `<Directory>` block and inside its `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block.  Don't know whether that really makes any sense?  I was expecting an error as I thought `RewriteEngine On` would have to be on the top level or something.

Answer (score 3):

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

RewriteLog needs to have a context of server config or virtual host.  Try this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 3
  </IfModule>
  ServerName somesite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite/html
  <Directory "/var/www/somesite/html">
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
      </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still get an error if I put `RewriteLogLevel 3` in the `<Directory>`.

Comment: Yep, you are right, RewriteLogLevel has to be moved up as well.  I've edited my answer to reflect the correct format.